# trying to fix buildTools

Tags: build-tools

I want to start programming plugins for Minecraft.
I looked up the official manual for setting up a Spigot Server via Build Tools, which just doesn't worked in some way.

Just to explain what I did:

I downloaded the latest BuildTools from the official website. Then I downloaded the GitCMD and the latest Java (Version 8) release.
Then I opened Git Bash in the directory where I saved the BuildTools.
I copied the needed code to start BuildTools from the BuildTools-Spigot-Website.

Code: `java -jar BuildTools.jar rev-- 1.8.8`

Then I run the code. Theoretically it is said that the BuildTools build a lot of documents and the spigot server to later set up a minecraft server. But not on me. When I run the code it says exactly this:

```
$ java -jar BuildTools.jar --rev 1.8.8
Loading BuildTools version: git-BuildTools-777d69d-121 (#121)
Java Version: Java 8
Current Path: C:\Users\yuzai\Eclipse\Serve 1.8.8\Build Tools\.
Please do not run BuildTools in a Dropbox, OneDrive, or similar. You can always copy the completed jars there later.
```

..and that's it. It doesn't build anything. Is there something I did wrong? Would be glad for help.

Comment: Are you running the build tools in DropBox or an online syncing service?